# HUGE latitude error from iPhone 4s

Tags: gps, accuracy, iphone

2015 April 15, I wandered around Little Rock, Arkansas, on bike, taking pictures with an iPhone 4s.  Cloudy day, though some photos show shadows.  Here are some of the metadata from three consecutive pictures taken around mid-day on the north bank of the Arkansas River:

```
GPSLatitude   GPSLongitude  GPSDateTime              DateTimeOriginal
34.752361     -92.266814    2015:04:15 17:30:30.93Z  2015:04:15 12:30:33
34.749186  !  -92.268372    2015:04:15 17:32:40.92Z  2015:04:15 12:32:42
34.752950     -92.267128    2015:04:15 17:33:43.96Z  2015:04:15 12:33:44
```

The one with the **!** maps almost four hundred meters away on the opposite side of the river.  All were taken outdoors with few trees around, and not close to any bridges.

**What would make *one* picture out of dozens so far off?**

Comment: My wife's iPhone often places us on the opposite direction outer lanes on a 12-lane highway with train tracks down the middle ("Travel 5 miles to make a U-turn...". It happens.

Comment: cloud cover/rain can also affect the gps signal. 2022 gps chipsets are also much more powerful and the newest mobile devices have dual band frequency gps which improves accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

I'd put the blame on the way iOS supplies locations to applications.  We had similar problems when testing a Bluetooth GNSS, iOS would report the GPS locations most of the time, but every now and then iOS would decide our cyclist was cycling along a road and give a few positions along the road, then jump back to the actual cycle path.  I don't know whether current iOS versions behave the same, I mostly work on Android and Windows now.

Android 10 shows similar weird behaviour with locations - if you log positions every second, mostly you'll get GNSS positions with accuracy estimates below 5M, every now and then you'll get positions with accuracy estimates at the 30M level which I think are from WiFi networks, and occasionally you'll get positions with accuracy estimates of 100s of M, I think those are from the cellular network.